# Proof of the limit of abs

Tags: limits

We have the expression to proof:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty}|{\frac{1}{\sqrt[n^2]{n}}|=1}
\end{align*}

What ways can we use for proving?

Comment: What did you try? Why are you applying the absolute value to a sequence of numbers all of which are greater than $0$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos oh, now I see the solution, sorry... We can replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
{\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{n^{2}}}} = \exp\left(-\frac{\log n}{n^2}\right)
$$
But
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log n}{n^2} = 0
$$
(either already known, or computed with L'Hospital)
so
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{n^{2}}}} = e^0 = 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Equality transformation:
\begin{align*}
{\frac{1}{\sqrt[n^2]{n}}}={\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{n^{2}}}}
\end{align*}

And replacing the variable:

\begin{align*}
{\frac{1}{n}=u, u \to 0}
\end{align*}
Because 
\begin{align*}
{n \to \infty}
\end{align*}

Steps of replacing:
\begin{align*}
{\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{n^{2}}}}={\frac{1}{n^{(\frac{1}{n})^2}}}={\frac{1}{n^{u^2}}}={(\frac{1}{n})}^{u^2}={u}^{u^2}
\end{align*}

So we got easy expression:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{u \to 0}|{{u}^{u^2}|=\lim_{u \to 0}|u^{u^2}|=\lim_{u \to 0}|u^{u}|=1}
\end{align*}

Comment: I believe $0^0$ is not defined.

Comment: @Epiksalad so, I editet this to limit of 0^0, what equals to 1

Answer (score 0):

Let $n >1$;

$a_n := n^{1/(n^2)}=(n^{1/n})^{1/n};$

$1\lt a_n \lt n^{1/n};$

Hence $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }a_n=1$;

What can you say about $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n$, where $b_n=\dfrac{1}{a_n}$.

Used: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{1/n}=1$.